# Security measures to take upon acquiring a new laptop?

Tags: vpn, firewalls, virtualization, operating-systems

I'm planning on buying a regular HP laptop. However, I'm still a novice when it comes to information security. I'm planning on using this laptop to SOLELY login to my bank accounts and NO OTHER website, via my school's secured WiFi connection. What steps would you take to secure an ordinary mid-range performance laptop to a maximum level? I know there are are plenty of resources on the internet that can help me get started and this may seem too broad of a question, but I'd really enjoy the insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to "secure" the computer. I do not think security is strictly an aspect of the computer and software. It matters what you do as a user on an ongoing basis.

- Since it is a new computer presumably the operating system is fresh. If it is not fresh install it from trusted sources. Use full disk encryption (FDE). Enabling FDE might require a re-installation depending upon the operating system. The penalty for using FDE will be that your computer is a little slower. By "a little" I mean that almost all people will not notice the difference. Use an operating system that is used by millions of people.
- Make sure you know the correct URI of the financial institution. Then bookmark it so that you do not subsequently visit the wrong website via keyboarding errors.
- Enter secrets such as passwords only on encrypted URIs. Know what the TLS (SSL) indicator looks like on your browser. It might be a green padlock next to the URI. It might be only that the URI begins with `https`.
- Use only a browser that is used by millions of other people. Unfortunately for new entrepreneurs, a large user base is an (imperfect) proxy for quality in security.
- Do not install keyloggers and spyware. Since you said you will only use it for banking then restrict your software to whatever the bank advises. This might be a browser or it might be the bank's own applications. Note that programs do not seek to identify themselves as keyloggers and spyware so it is a non-trivial problem to avoid installing them in the general case of a computer being used for a variety of purposes.
- Do not run arbitrary programs whether installed or not. Programs that you haven't installed but potentially can run would include programs that ask you if you want to run them immediately upon a download or programs stored on a removable drive.
- Do not let people video record your keyboarding or other actions on the computer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. What would be there difference If I'd use an OS like Qubes OS, adding to it a virtual machine, to then use on that VM a live USB as an operating system, and finally connect using Tor provided I have a trusted paid VPN client running in the background? Or instead of running Tor, run a browser like Chrome.

Comment: Very often more is less. What I mean by this is that in adding "additional security programs" you are unexpectedly lengthening your potential attack surface. So now you are relying on your VM software being secure, Qubes OS being secure and indeed everything on the VM seen as you're entering your bank details into it. There's no need for you to use a VM if you're not downloading a lot of potentially dangerous stuff. It's used to protect your main OS but in this case all sensitive info is being stored within the VM itself so it makes no sense.

Comment: With regard to a VPN/TOR then of course that's good. I would actually recommend using TOR as your browser, seen as it doesn't run JS and as such is immune to the majority of browser exploit kits. Still, banks might block connections over TOR. It's still very important that you use SSL/TLS, especially when using a VPN to prevent some bad actor from sniffing your traffic.

Comment: @CillianCollins Your bank already has: your name, one or more secrets of yours. As far as I understand, using Tor or a VPN is going to disguise your IP. I do not think your IP is a secret that your bank seeks but go ahead with disguising your IP if you think it is worth the trouble. Your bank will not know where you are when you travel but they already know where you live and many other details and you trusted them with your money.

Comment: That's really not at all the point of this thread. The point is that it will prevent a 3rd party from reading your traffic. For example, your ISP.

Comment: @CillianCollins If the banking traffic is TLS (SSL) then there will be no benefit to the ISP or anybody else in reading the traffic.

Comment: And you're simply making assumptions here. VPN is adding to the security of this situation, not taking away from it at all. Why assume it's using SSL everywhere, when it might not be? Why assume that a 0day affecting SSL won't be discovered in the near future and used to target people's banks? It's a long shot, but it's happened in the past, and it's better to be safe than sorry. I'm all of the theory of more security not always being better, but in this case it's simply not true.

Comment: @CillianCollins It's my understanding that if it's not encrypted on any single hop on the internet then your identifier password pair is exposed so hiding your IP with a VPN will not protect the account. If I'm wrong somebody will correct me.

Comment: Take for example if someone gets some access to the bank and they are able to log information of users. Running a VPN ensures the anonymity of the user and protects them from the attacker.

Comment: @CillianCollins "able to log information of users" you mean like the bank card and password. No VPN will protect against this problem.

Comment: No, I mean logging information such as IP address.

Answer (score 2):

Despite your already accepting an answer, I'll add mine.

**Most importantly, us two factor authentication (2FA) with your bank!**

You need not dedicate a laptop to your banking. If you are worried about the laptop, use a bootable non-persistent OS, there are dozens of Linux variants or you could even use Windows-to-Go if you want Windows. This will bypass everything on your laptop drives that might be there.

FDE is nice for many reasons, but for banking purposes you only need to protect your bank information. This can be done strictly in your head or in an encrypted folder on a thumb drive.

The operating system you use is completely irrelevant.

Forget Tor and VPN's for banking purposes. Most banks blacklist Tor nodes even if you wanted to use them. You have no interest in hiding your identity, quite the reverse in fact.